# Is it possible to use Juju to install Openstack from local unsigned repository?

Tags: juju, openstack

Is it possible to set Juju to allow an unsigned private deb repo?

I am trying to automate setting up a local APT repo on one of my MAAS/Juju nodes (via a custom charm), and install custom Openstack packages onto my intended Openstack nodes from there. I reviewed this,

[How do I add a public key for a private debian repo when using juju to deploy a service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674882/how-do-i-add-a-public-key-for-a-private-debian-repo-when-using-juju-to-deploy-a)

But I don't need the repo to be signed.

Comment: Are you deploying the openstack packages from your charm?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code if a debian repository needs to be added.

You will need to import the [charmhelpers](https://pythonhosted.org/charmhelpers/) python library into your charm. If the charmhelpers directory is under the ***hooks/*** directory add the following code to your ***install*** hook.

```
from charmhelpers.fetch import configure_sources 
configure_sources(update=True)
```

You will also be required to add two configs into your config.yaml

```
install_sources:
  default: 'ppa:<custom-ppa>/stable'
  type: string
  description: Provide the install source URL.
install_keys:
  default: null
  type: string
  description: Provide the respective keys of the install sources.
```

You can pass configs as follows in your config.yaml:

```
charm-name:
  install_sources: "deb https://stub:key@private.example.com/ubuntu trusty main"
```

Deploy add the --config flag when deploying the charm:

```
juju deploy --config config.yaml charm-name
```

---

The install_sources value can be a URL or sources.list entry, as supported by: add-apt-repository. Examples:

- "ppa:charmers/example"
- "deb https://stub:key@private.example.com/ubuntu trusty main"
- 'proposed:' may be used to enable the standard 'proposed' pocket for the release.
- 'cloud:' may be used to activate official cloud archive pockets, such
  as 'cloud:icehouse'
- 'distro' may be used as a noop